# In Cypress how to count a selection of items and get the length?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I'm starting to learn Cypress. I have a 4 row table (with a class of datatable). I can verify the number of rows this way:

```js
cy.get('.datatable').find('tr').each(function(row, i){
        expect(i).to.be.lessThan(4)
})
```

This is fine, but it seems awkward, since I just want to count the length and don't really need to access the stuff in the rows, and I assume it's faster to do one thing than do 4 things.

If I log the selection (not sure what else to call it):

```js
cy.log(cy.get('.datatable').find('tr'))
```

it comes out as `[object Object]` and I'm not quite sure how to deconstruct that, which suggests to me that I'm thinking about this all wrong.

If I try:

```js
expect(cy.get('.datatable').find('tr')).to.have.lengthOf(4)
```

I get `AssertionError: expected { Object (chainerId, firstCall) } to have a property 'length'`

If I try:

```js
expect(Cypress.$('.datatable > tr')).to.have.lengthOf(4)
```

I get `AssertionError: expected { Object (length, prevObject, ...) } to have a length of 4 but got 0` so at least it has a length here?

If I log that method of selection I get `Object{4}`. I'm not sure where to go from here. It seems like this would be a very common thing to deal with.

Comment: My client uses only Chrome (it's not a public facing app). We have moved away from Cypress as we are converting the app to Angular and are now using Karma and Jasmine (which are inbuilt with the framework). I found Cypress quite easy to work with but I didn't choose it (nor did I choose Angular); however I would have to say that the extensive documentation for Cypress is probably very attractive. When testing is not your ken and more of a chore, having extensive docs with good examples helps you get up and running quicker.

Answer (score 286, accepted):

Found a solution, This works to check a count of items:

```
cy.get('.datatable').find('tr').should('have.length', 4)
```

This does not work with the `Cypress.$()` method of notation.

Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#Length

Comment: This is a good way to test length, but you can't return the length this way. To return you need to use the Promise chain `.then(elm => elm.length)`

Comment: Looks like .should('have.length', 4) checks for “at least 4”. The other solution, using .its('length').should('eq', 4), checks for exact equality.

Comment: the question was "how to count a selection of items and get the length?" and NOT "how to check" - the goal is to return count outside of the chaining....

Comment: For `Cypress.$` approach, you could try `expect(Cypress.$(".datatable").find('tr').length === 4)` Though Katarine's suggestion would be better choice. Using `Cypress.$` would be best used more in a combination with other checks in Cypress.

Comment: @png Do you mean we can get length like this? `eleLength = cy.get(selector).should('have.length.greaterThan', 0).then(elm => elm.length);`

Answer (score 128):

You can also get the length of a selection of items [through its property](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/its.html), for example:

```
cy.get('.datatable').find('tr').its('length').should('eq', 4)
cy.get('.datatable').find('tr').its('length').should('be.gte', 4)
```

In addition to `should('have.length', 4)`

[image]
I tested with Cypress version 3.1.0 and 3.2.0.

Comment: tried these & get an error: TypeError: $table.find(...).its is not a function

Comment: @SteveStaple I tried again with the current latest version of Cypress, v3.2.0, it still works. See my updated answer with a screenshot.

Comment: For flexibility reasons I prefer this solution over the `.should('have.length', length)` expectation, because `.its('length')` provides **greater flexibility on your assertions**, e.g. greater than or less than.

Comment: Just an FYI, you can also use greater than or less than with `should` like this: `should('have.length.gte', length)`

Answer (score 44):

if you want more flexible and have a dynamic result use this.

```
cy.get('.listings-grid')
  .find('.listing')
  .then(listing => {
    const listingCount = Cypress.$(listing).length;
    expect(listing).to.have.length(listingCount);
  });
```

Comment: this gets filled listingCount  internally only, cannot return it outside of .then()... .its('length') also returns chaining object, not an integer

Comment: This test is going to be flaky because only the last then will be retried throughout the timeout.

Comment: @SashaBond why not make a variable higher in scope, then modify it in your .then(). that should fix the scope issue.

Answer (score 20):

One option is to use "have.length" ...

```
cy.get('.datatable tr').should('have.length', 4)
```

...another option is to use should

```
cy.get('.datatable tr').should(($tr) => {
    expect($tr).to.have.length(4)
})
```

...or then (synchronous queries)

```
cy.get('.datatable').then(($table) => {
  // synchronously query to find length of elements
  expect($table.find('td').length).to.equal(4)
})
```

Comment: Thie first one is the best solution if you have dynamic content - otherwise .get will work immediately and return the wrong amount of find, which is waited on even though the real number changed. This solution will wait on the correct number.

Answer (score 5):

From the [cypress API docs .should() section](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Function), using an [arrow function](http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies):

```
cy.get('.datatable').find('tr').should(($listOfElements) => {
   expect($listOfElements).to.have.length(4)
   // any other assertions, for example the below one
   // expect($listOfElements).to.have.any.keys('key1', 'key2')
})
```

This approach will allow you to use [Chai BDD notation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#BDD-Assertions) and assert more than one thing on your list of elements.

Comment: Other assertions can be chained with `.and()` see [should.html#Multiple-Assertions](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Multiple-Assertions). Less noise IMO.

Answer (score 3):

```
cy
  .get('ul[data-qa="qa-navbar"] li')      // selector 
  .should('have.length', 5)               //  Assertion
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Seems like a repeat of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46850775/6243352). Consider upvoting the accepted answer rather than reposting it.

Answer (score 1):

- **.children** (selector(byId, class, custom attribute) yields DOM
  elements and retry untill defaultCommandTimeout exceeds.

  cypress config [defaultCommandTimeout](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Timeouts)
- once **DOM** elements **exists and yielded** added `length` assertion.

```
<ul data-qa="qa-navbar">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Our Team</li>
  <li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```

```
    cy
      .get('[data-qa="qa-navbar"]') // selector
      .children() // get direct decendents 
      .should('have.length', 5); // add assertion to have lenght of 5
```

Answer (score 1):

My use case was to compare that, say no. of "i" icons on the page should match the no. of table rows. So, this solution worked for it i.e. when I wanted to compare the no. of elements of one selector vs the other

```
cy.get('first element').its('length').then((val)=>{
     cy.get('second element).its('length').should('eq',val)
})
```

Writing `then` after `its` captures the requested property (in this case, length) and within the first `then` block, we do a compare by getting the length of the second element

Answer (score -1):

to get the length you need to use cypress commands:

```
    cy.get('[ng-repeat="item in catalog"]').then(($el) => { 
        const itemCount = Cypress.$($el).length;
        cy.log(itemCount)
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 - In the element locator "aria-setsize" property to find the "number of items in the current set of listitems or treeitems" can be used.
 - Within ".then" function, for the previously yielded element. Use ".length" jquery as below.
 - To find the list of: Best Sellers in Computers & Accessories, in "Amazon.in" home screen.

it('test', () => {
        cy.visit('https://www.amazon.in/ref=nav_logo')
        cy.wait(3000)
        cy.get('#desktop-5 li[aria-setsize]')
        .then(($el) => {
         const count= $el.length
         cy.log(count)
        })

    })
```

Answer (score -3):

Body variable is already resolved as you're in .then() part of the promise:

```
cy.get("body").then($body => {
    cy.log($body.find(".datatable tr").length);
});`
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.