# In Cypress how to count the number of rows in a table?

Tags: javascript, laravel, cypress, web-component-tester

I am doing E2E tests with cypress.
i have to count the number of rows in a table which are different from case to case.

in normal javascript I just write this to get the number of total rows of the column

```
document.getElementById('hometable').getElementsByTagName("tr").length-1
```

unfortunately in cypress i get the following error:

```
 document.getElementById('hometable').getElementsByTagName("tr").length-1

VM298:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
    at <anonymous>:1:38
(anonymous) @ VM298:1
```

I tried to count like this but got nothing

```
cy.get('hometable').find('tr').each(function(row, i){
        expect(i)
})

$Chainer {userInvocationStack: "", specWindow: Window, chainerId: "chainer99", firstCall: false, useInitialStack: false}
chainerId: "chainer99"
firstCall: false
specWindow: Window {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 0, frames: Window, …}
useInitialStack: false
userInvocationStack: ""
__proto__: Object
```

i can't figure out where it returns me the number of rows

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46850694/in-cypress-how-to-count-a-selection-of-items-and-get-the-length answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is correct, You can use the `each()`. There is one more parameter that you can add to each, **list** and this will give you the count for the number of rows. You can check the [cypress document for each()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html#Yields). Make sure the locator is correct.

```
cy.get('#hometable > tr').each(function(row, i, list) {}).then(function(list) {
      //list will give you the count of tr
    }
```